# sms retriever api 11 digit hash not working on PlayStore App

Tags: android, keystore

I worked on sms retriever API and it worked successfully on debug mode and when I archived my app in release mode it worked there also when I installed unsigned app on my phone. But after few days when I tried my playstore app the sms retriever api was not picking up the code automatically. I tried different techniques to generate the 11 digit code for playstore but it didn't worked. I even downloaded my app signing certificate from Google Play COnsole and generated 11 digit code from that .der certififcate but it did not worked as well.

I used this command to genrate the 11 digit hash

> keytool -exportcert -keystore deployment_cert.der | xxd -p | tr -d
>   "[:space:]" | echo -n com.myapp.abc `cat` | shasum -a 256  | tr -d
>   "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11

If anyone have any other solution that might help then please share.

Comment: Facing the same issue have you got any solution yet?

Comment: No, Still waiting for someone to answer on this post

Comment: @ZeeshanShakil have you got any solution?